# What is the difference between an "iOS App Development" certificate and an "In-House and Ad Hoc" one?

Tags: ios, developer-program, certificate

I am a member of my employer's corporate Apple account, and I am building a test app. To get it deployed, I created an "iOS App Development" certificate, after registering my device's UDID as required, and that all works fine.

Now, searching Stack Overflow and other places, I find information like to install to a second device I can just plug the new device in and copy across from XCode, without using up another of my 100 device registrations. Furthermore, an "In-House and Ad Hoc" certificate will allow me to share the app throughout the enterprise.

However, there are still a number of questions outstanding:

1. Does the iOS App Development certificate give me any extra rights on my registered device?
2. Does the iOS App Development certificate give me any extra rights on unregistered devices?
3. Do I actually need an iOS App Development certificate, or will an In-House and Ad Hoc one do everything I need?
4. Does an In-House and Ad Hoc certificate have no technical install limitations, just the legal force of the user agreement?

Comment: Lets close this to clean up what's really being solved here. We generally close two part questions and ask that individual questions get asked.

Comment: Also - perhaps hit us up on [meta] and/or [chat] if its not clear where the line between developer ( Stack Overflow) and user/enterprise ( Ask Different ) lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Source of everything I'm about to say: iOS developership.</sub>

#### First of all...

You **can not** deploy a development app on a second device without using another one of your 100 devices. You just can't.

#### Now, the list of questions.

1. **Yes**, you can run development apps that haven't been signed with a distribution certificate.
2. **No**. The development cert may only be installed on registered devices.
3. **Yes**, if you are serious about development. You could get by with only an ad-hoc cert, but it would be cumbersome, and you wouldn't be able to use hugely helpful Xcode debugging features like Breakpoints and logging.
4. **I don't know**, but I would assume so.

Comment: Thanks for these answers! I'd obviously misunderstood the ability to install to a second device from XCode. So, an important reason to use a development certificate (and a key difference from an Ad Hoc cert) is to enable debugging on a physical device?

Comment: @KenY-N Yes, it enables debugging tethered to Xcode, giving you some nice info when debugging stuff.